# Расстановка запятых

Tags: запятая

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужны ли запятые на месте круглых скобок: "Той осенью () в серые дождливые дни () я предпочитала сидеть дома".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Той осенью, в серые дождливые дни, я предпочитала сидеть дома. 
   В этом предложение обособление практически обязательно, так как его задает структура предложения. В необособленном варианте мы должны соединить в одну фразу два распространенных обстоятельства, а это сделать сложно - предложение не читается. Таким образом, определенная семантика (желание выделить оборот как уточняющий, подчеркнуть его значимость) заставляет автора выбирать такую структуру предложения, где оборот должен обособляться.
2. Теперь попробуем построить вариант, где возможны оба решения, например: Вечерами, в дождливые дни, я предпочитала сидеть дома. Мы сократили объем обстоятельств, и теперь можем прочитать предложение с обособлением или без него. Можно считать второе обстоятельство уточняющим при обособлении или считать, что это неоднородные обстоятельства при отсутствии запятых. Это АВТОРСКИЙ выбор.
3. Вечерами в ту осень я предпочитала сидеть дома.  Структура этого предложения не позволяет обособить нераспространенное обстоятельство, также такое обособление не нужно и по смыслу. Это неоднородные обстоятельства.

Таким образом, при построении или разборе текста следует учитывать не только его семантику, но и структуру предложений. Иногда можно выбирать между двумя решениями, а в других случаях мы такой возможности не имеем.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

Здесь речь идет об интонационно-структурном анализе. Любое предложение можно представить в виде набора фраз – речевых отрезков с одним движением тона вверх или вниз.  Простое предложение состоит из двух таких отрезков, выражающих «тему – рему», то есть о чем говорим и что говорим.  Если мы не обособим обстоятельство, то это будет выглядеть так:

(1) Той осенью в серые дождливые дни↑ (пауза)  я предпочитала сидеть дома↓ При отсутствии обособления, читая предложение,  мы можем сделать короткую паузу между обстоятельствами, но  не должны выделять тоническим ударением слово ОСЕНЬЮ, должны как бы «проскакивать» это слово. А  здесь это особенно неудобно, учитывая его собственное ударение на первом слоге - мы просто «спотыкаемся» об него. А представьте себе, если мы еще распространим обстоятельства, разве мы сможем тогда всё это прочитать «на одном дыхании»!

(2) А теперь обособим обстоятельство: Той  осенью, ↑ (пауза)  в серые дождливые дни,↑ (пауза)  я предпочитала сидеть дома↓ Теперь у нас три фразы примерно одинакового объема, которые прекрасно читаются. Здесь шрифтом выделены те слова, на которых делается тоническое ударение – мы как бы «пропеваем» эти гласные, удлиняя их и повышая или понижая их тон.

С помощью такого анализа вы можно решать и объяснять  пунктуационные задачи для себя, а объяснять их решение для других можно классическим способом, определяя грамматику и семантику выражения. В нашем случае можно считать, что это распространенное уточняющее обстоятельство с дополнительным значением причины (как говорил Виктор).

Comment: София, спасибо Вам за такой развернутый ответ. В таком случае я бы хотела спросить, а вот если бы предложение имело вид: "Той осенью, в серые дождливые дни, я предпочитала читать книги, оставленные мне сестрой". Запятые были бы нужны? Просто я не вполне поняла Ваш пункт №1 (про обстоятельства): "В необособленном варианте мы должны соединить в одну фразу два распространенных обстоятельства, а это сделать сложно - предложение не читается". Разъясните, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2):

Слова "в серые дождливые дни" вполне могут быть рассмотрены как уточняющее обстоятельство при более общем, уточняемом понятии "той осенью". Кроме того, в этих словах  "в серые дождливые дни" имеется и причинный отттенок значения, так что запятые вполне уместны.

Comment: Но, как я поняла, они не являются обязательными?..

Comment: Вы правы, это факультативный знак,можно прочитать и без пауз, без уточнения: "Той осенью  в серые дождливые дни  я предпочитала сидеть дома".

Comment: Т.е. отсутствие запятых в данном предложении не будет ошибкой?
А если так: "Той осенью, в серые дождливые дни я предпочитала сидеть дома"? Просто я не вполне понимаю эти случаи, когда можно ставить, а можно не ставить знаки препинания...

Comment: И все же лучше запятые поставить, ведь по форме и по сути эти слова на самом деле уточняют, конкретизируют, когда именно и по какой причине автор фразы предпочитала сидеть дома

Comment: 1. Осень ещё бывает сухой и солнечной, как вот октябрь несколько лет назад.
2. В предложении есть некоторая искусственность: в серые дождливые дни только и остаётся по *дефиниции*, что сидеть дома. Так какое же здесь уточнение? Как за наименьшее зло считаю форму без препинации.

Comment: Hermit, извините, я Вас не вполне поняла. Т.е. в предложениях: "Той осенью в серые дождливые дни я сидела дома" и "Той осенью в ясные погожие дни я сидела дома" будет разная пунктуация?

Comment: Этот пост — офтоп темы.
Пунктуация в обоих предложениях одна: точка в конце предложения. 
Но я сказал другое, не в тему напрямую, скорее всего. Оба предложения заслуживают места в учебнике для иностранцев, изучающих русский язык. Как упражнения на составление простых предложений, не более того. У носителя языка они вызывают недоумение. Особенно первое. Второе же допускает приемлемое понимание, но всё равно требует перестройки: "Даже в ясные погожие дни той осени я сидела дома". И читателю ясно: русская хандра ею овладела. 
Извините, **Ммарина**, больше добавить мне нечего.

Comment: Семантика отдельно взятого предложения, действительно, может вызвать вопросы. В обособленном варианте я представляю себе это так:Той осенью вы меня чаще могли застать дома, так как осень в большинстве случаев дождлива, и эта исключением не стала - обособленный оборот намекает нам на это. Если же и дальше речь пойдет о погоде, то можно предположить и НЕОБОСОБЛЕННЫЙ вариант с ИЗМЕНЕННОЙ ИНТОНАЦИЕЙ:Той осенью (небольшая пауза) в серые ДОЖДЛИВЫЕ дни я предпочитала сидеть дома, а при хорошей погоде старалась погулять В ПАРКЕ.

Comment: 1) Той осенью, в серые дождливые дни, я предпочитала сидеть дома.
2)Той осенью, в серые дождливые дни я предпочитала сидеть дома.
3)Той осенью в серые дождливые дни я предпочитала сидеть дома.
Предложение 3, может быть, и допустимо (с каких-то позиций), но оно скучно, невыразительно, безынтонационно. Лучше его отвергнуть. Остаются 1) и 2). На мой взгляд, 1) предпочтительнее. В 2)"Той осенью" кажется архитектурным излишеством (две части предложения - поясняют одна другую). В 1) в другие дни она, видимо, могла ходить куда-то ("словам тесно, а мысли просторно" - как у В. И. Ленина, помните?).

Comment: София:  В обособленном варианте я представляю себе это так:Той осенью вы меня чаще могли застать дома, так как осень в большинстве случаев дождлива, и эта исключением не стала - обособленный оборот намекает нам на это.

Вот такой оборот меня устраивает: "Той осенью, серой дождливыми днями, я предпочитала сидеть дома". Вот так убедительно, что всю-всю осень просидела дома. И ясно почему.

Comment: Русак: "Той осенью, в серые дождливые дни я предпочитала сидеть дома". 
Слишком смелое решение: обстоятельства "вступают" в однородную связь, а это вряд ли будет одобрено орфографической комиссией. В этом случае надо будет доказать, что в указанное время не было ни одного солнечного дня, только тогда одно множество полностью включает в себя другое.

Comment: @София. Если это моё авторское предложение, значит, мне и доказывать орфографической комиссии ничего не надо (т.е. я этим предложением самоуверенно хочу подчеркнуть, что в указанное время не было ни одного солнечного дня). Другое дело, что читателю до таких тонкостей дела нет: не всякий поймёт то, что я хотел сказать. А значит, такое предложение, в принципе возможное, - слишком заумное  с точки зрения внимательного читателя и весьма неудачное как художественный приём для характеристики осени. Спасибо Вам за тонкий анализ предложения.